# Things like Gender and Status in my Domain is ValueObjects?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I have a Person Entity in my domain, this person have Gender and Status property, this properties are ValueObjects?

```
Gender = { Male, Female }

Status = { Active, Inactive }
```

I'm using EF, I'm thinking of creating enums for them. I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Lookie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526339/how-to-work-with-enums-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm doing something wrong?

Nope. This is fine, completely standard.

Comment: Yes. They are like "6" or "red". Their value is their identity, and therefore they should be value types.