# How to sort with a CASE statement in an EntityDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I'm using a `CASE` statement in my EntityDataSource to do custom sorting. Consider the following code:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="myEntityDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=MySQLEntities1" 
    DefaultContainerName="MySQLEntities1" 
    EnableFlattening="False" 
    EntitySetName="Persons" 
    EntityTypeFilter="Persons"
    OrderBy="it.[Pack], 
             CASE it.[Type] 
                WHEN 'MAN' THEN 1 
                WHEN 'VROUW' THEN 2 
                WHEN 'KIND' THEN 3 
             END, 
             it.[BirthDate] ASC" />
```

In T-SQL this would be a perfecty normal way of sorting, but used in the `EntityDataSource`  it throws the following exception:

> The query syntax is not valid. Near identifier 'it', line 11, column
>   21.

How can I get this type of sorting to work in my `EntityDataSource`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying the very same thing today. I discovered on the Entity SQL Reference site that you apparently have to use `CASE WHEN` and cannot use `CASE [value] WHEN`. This approach, although not as it would be in T-SQL, did work for me. So your code should look like this:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="myEntityDataSource" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="name=MySQLEntities1"      
DefaultContainerName="MySQLEntities1"      
EnableFlattening="False"      
EntitySetName="Persons"      
EntityTypeFilter="Persons"     
OrderBy="it.[Pack],               
CASE 
WHEN it.[Type] = 'MAN' THEN 1                  
WHEN it.[Type] = 'VROUW' THEN 2                  
WHEN it.[Type] = 'KIND' THEN 3 END, it.[BirthDate] ASC" />
```

[MSDN Entity SQL Reference: 'CASE'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399229.aspx)

Comment: A-MA-ZING! You saved me a LOOOOOT of time! Muchos gracias!!! If I had some beer, you would get it!

Comment: @Kees C. Bakker : Great, my greetings that you've found the solution! It was interesting for me to why EF was not able handling `CASE` inside the `ORDER BY`

Comment: How to use CASE in Select