# SQL: Exception to an otherwise sorted result set

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Using Oracle 11g

I want a single exception to an otherwise sorted table

```
select fruit as popluar_choices  
from menu 
order by fruit /* Exception put 'grapefruit' at top of list */
```

Desired Result

```
popular_choices
-----------
grapefruit
apple
fig
kiwi
lemon
pear
```

It's similar to this post:
[How to apply non standard SQL column sort order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278950/how-to-apply-non-standard-sql-column-sort-order)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  select fruit as popluar_choices  
    from menu 
order by case fruit when 'grapefruit' then 0
                                      else 1
              end,
         fruit
```

Comment: Only ten seconds apart, and the only difference between your answer and mine was that I used 1 and 2 in the case, rather than 0 and 1. Let's go with yours.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT fruit AS popular_choices FROM menu
ORDER BY 
    CASE fruit
        WHEN 'grapefruit' THEN ''
        ELSE fruit
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select fruit as popluar_choices  
from menu 
order by CASE fruit = 'grapefruit' THEN '__' ELSE fruit END
```

Comment: Will fail in case if there is a fruit with name starts with `^`

Comment: If any `menu` may have no `fruit` (`fruit` is `''`), your answer will not move grapefruit to the top of the list.