# MySQL SELECT rows which respond to specific MULTIPLE values in one of the columns

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-value

I've looked all over the Web, and in StackOverflow as well, and have found many similar topics, but none that answers specifically my needs. So I'm sending this out there, knowing there's probably some little thing I'm missing in order for it to work.

Let's imagine the following table:

```
      location  |   title   | description | quantity 
    ============|===========|=============|==========
      shelf     |   apple   |    red      |    2
      drawer    |   banana  |    yellow   |    4
      shelf     |   kiwi    |    green    |    2
      cupboard  |   lemon   |    yellow   |    1
      fridge    |   melon   |    orange   |    3
      drawer    |   peach   |    orange   |    1
```

What I want to do is select from this table all items that are either in the `drawer` or on the `shelf` (so `drawer` AND `shelf`) and then order them by, for example, first, location ascending and, second, quantity descending.

So what I have (after searching all over the web) is the following code, which is the only one that doesn't return an error, **but it doesn't return any items either:**

`SELECT * FROM items WHERE location = 'shelf' AND location = 'drawer' ORDER BY location ASC, quantity DESC`

Where am I going wrong? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated!

Usually questions go toward how to select values from multiple tables and then join them. However, I need values from only one table; however, these values need to respond to specific multiple values they share.

Comment: what is your desired output based on the data above?

Comment: just use `OR` or `IN`, [SQLFiddle Demo >>clickHERE<<](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de7b2/7)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE location = 'shelf' or location = 'drawer'
ORDER BY location ASC, quantity DESC
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE location in ('shelf','drawer')
ORDER BY location ASC, quantity DESC
```

although for just two items, I'd probably go with the first myself, 3 or more, i might use in()

Additional Info: The reason why you are getting no records returned is because you are using `AND` in your condition. Remember that there is one and only one value for every column in a row.

Comment: As I said "there's probably some little thing I'm missing"... Thanks a bunch, Mike! The first recommendation certainly did the trick (and makes me feel quite dumb). Instead of `AND`, should have used `OR`, because `AND` means I'm looking items where the location meets all those terms at once, and not one or the other.

Comment: I found the second code you mention somewhere last night. I, too, thought it better in order to list several values (as I need to list at least five). However, last night I tried it and it didn't work for me. It returned an error message saying the column "shelf" and "drawer", for example, couldn't be found. Like it was looking for "location" in "shelf" or "drawer"... However, I've copied and pasted yours and it works fine. Don't know what I could have done wrong last night!

Comment: Quick question, Mike. Do you know of any way I could make an exception in the order process. Say if I wanted "peach" to be specifically listed first even though it starts with "p" or "apple", last, even though it starts with "a"?

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but I'd recommend you make a new question explaining exactly what you need there. The reason I say this, is with that the query is getting much more complex, and I could probably come up with an answer, but I'd be afraid that it wouldn't be the best answer. There's lots of smart people here, and I'd be interested in a better answer than I'd come up with as well honestly.

Comment: Never mind. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284536/sql-exception-to-an-otherwise-sorted-result-set

Answer (score 2):

try to use this.....

In case you want to use it in php you can modify my code and replace it with yours. I had a similar problem when i was developing this:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cancer WHERE Age ='1'OR Age = '2' OR Age = '3'OR Age = '4'OR Age = '5'OR Age = '6'OR Age = '7'OR Age = '8'OR Age = '9'")
```

In case of sql, use:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE location = 'shelf' or location = 'drawer'
ORDER BY location ASC, quantity DESC
```